# I am trying to calculate 8-bit parity in a 64-bit word in C

Tags: c

I have written a small function to calculate even parity for each 8-bit block in a 64-bit word. The function is producing incorrect results.

The following is the output for Ukey = 0x666F6F6261723132

Incorrect Output:

01100110
01101111
01101111
01100010
01100001
01110010
00110001
00110010

Correct Output:

Correct Even Parity:
01100110
01101111
01101111
01100011
01100000
01110010
00110000
00110011

KEYBITSLEN is defined as 64

BYTELEN is defined as 8

```
void KeyParity (uint64_t *Ukey)
{
        int ParityBit;
        int i, j;
   
        ParityBit = 0;
   
        for (i = 0; i < KEYBITSLEN; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < BYTELEN; j++)
            {
                if(*(Ukey+i) & (0x01 << j))
                ParityBit = !ParityBit;
            }
            if (i % 8 == 7)
            {
                *(Ukey+i) = ParityBit;
                ParityBit = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to get parity on? The value of `Ukey` itself, or is `Ukey` really a pointer to a series of `uint64_t` values and you want to get the parity of each `uint64_t` value? What is `Ukey` really pointing to? Can you please try to [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre] (with hard-coded values)?

Comment: But `parity-bit` needs to be a separate bit. You're losing data using one of the `data-bit` as `parity-bit`.

Comment: I thought I did provide a correct example. . The test hex value i(Ukey) is  0x666F6F6261723132. The function receives a pointer to the hex value. The correct bit values are also provided together with the incorrect results from the function.

Comment: You might want to add a note about big endian being the requirement.

Comment: So `Ukey` is pointing to a *single* `uint64_t` value? It's not pointing to the first element of an array? Because when you do `*(Ukey+i)` you treat `Ukey` as an array, and `*(Ukey+i)` is *exactly* the same as `Ukey[i]`. So your loops doesn't get individual bytes of a single `uint64_t` value, and if all you have is a single value (why pass it as a pointer then?) then you will go out of bounds.

Comment: Without a proper [mre] (preferably with hard-coded values) it's hard to help you. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

This line looks suspicious:

```
if(*(Ukey+i) & (0x01 << j))
```

So does this line:

```
*(Ukey+i) = ParityBit;
```

When  `i != 0`, `UKey+i` is pointing to an entirely different 64-bit value from what `Ukey` points to in undefined memory space. Unless `Ukey` is pointing to an element of an array, this is undefined behavior.

Maybe this is closer to what you really want:

```
uint8_t KeyParity(uint64_t UKey)
{
    uint8_t result = 0;
    bool odd = false;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        if ((1ULL << i) & UKey)
        {
            odd = !odd;
        }

        if ((i % 8) == 7)
        {
            uint8_t parity = odd ? 1 : 0;
            parity = parity << (i/8);
            result = result | parity;
            odd = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In the title you ask for "8-bit parity of a 64-bit word", but then in the body you say "even parity of each 8-bit block in a 64-bit word".  These are two totally different things.  Worse, these are both 8-bit values, but your "desired output" is 64 bits for a 64 bit input (which makes no sense).

You could try either:

```
// compute the 8-bit parity of a 64 bit number
uint8_t EightBitParity(uint64_t val) {
    val ^= val >> 32;
    val ^= val >> 16;
    val ^= val >> 8;
    return val & 0xff;
}

// compute parity of each 8-bit byte of a 64-bit number;
uint8_t ParityOfBytes(uint64_t val) {
    val ^= val >> 4;
    val ^= val >> 2;
    val ^= val >> 1;
    val &= 0x0101010101010101;
    val |= val >> 28;
    val |= val >> 14;
    val |= val >> 7;
    return val & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify. There are eight (8), 8-bit blocks in a 64-bit word. I am trying to determine the parity (assuming even parity) of each of those 8-bit blocks The least significant bit of each 8-block will be set to achieve even parity over the non-parity, (data) 7 bits. The second block of code you have provided may help me resolve this however. Thanks.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks Lundin it was the "endianness" that was the problem.